# <input> calling a PHP function using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a PHP function using AJAX to check if the pressed button is the right button.

But I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using this as `<input>` code :

```
<?php
     $i=0;
     while ($i<4){
?>
    <input style="background-color: <?php echo $buttonColors[$i]; ?>" onclick="echoHello(<?php echo $i?>)" type="submit" value="<?php echo $buttonName[$i]; ?>">
<?php $i=$i+1; } ?>
```

and I'm trying to call a PHP function when the button is clicked. I tried this :

```
 <script>
        function echoHello()
        {
            alert("<?php hello(); ?>");
        }
    </script>
    <?php

    function hello() {

        echo "Hello World";
    }
    ?>
```

This worked so I tried to change this to :

```
<script>
        function echoHello(num)
        {
            alert("<?php hello(num); ?>");
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    function hello($num) {
        if($num == 1) {
        echo "Correct button!!!";
    } else {
        echo "WRONG BUTTON";
    }
    ?>
```

But this didn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And where's the ajax, what you're doing doesn't make sense at all, the if statement is executed on the serverside before the page is even sent to the browser, long before any button is clicked. What you could do is just echo the PHP variable to a javascript variable, then do the if condition in javascript instead, as you don't really need ajax for this.

Comment: better to echo the <script> tags and info inside the php response..

Comment: Why you have that <?php
     $i=0;
     while ($i<4){
?> there ?

Comment: Athanasios the while is because i have 4 buttons where you can choose from. Adeneo I want to parse a variable from HTML to PHP for this you need Ajax, atleast thats what i read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have quite some thing mixed up here.
I would suggest just writing out the buttons, and pass the buttons value to the javascript:

```
<?php
    $i=0;
    while ($i<4){
?>
<input onclick="echoHello(this.value)" type="submit" value="<?php echo $buttonName[$i]; ?>">
<?php 
     $i=$i+1; 
    } ?>
```

and then in your javascript (after adding all the [jQuery goodness](http://jquery.com/download/)):

```
function echoHello(btnValue) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "formhandler.php",
      data: { buttonValue: btnValue }
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
}
```

The javascript above will send the button value to your 'formhandler.php' page, using AJAX.
In the 'formhandler.php', you could then check what the value of $_POST["buttonValue"] is.

Using your setup, together with [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), [PHP](http://nz.php.net/json_encode) and JSON, it could be something like this:

```
function echoHello(btnValue) {
    $.getJSON('page.php', {
        choice: btnValue
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        // based on $_GET["choice"], your PHP could render some JSON like:
        // {"background":"image.jpg","fields":["newValue1", "newValue2", "newValue3"]}

        // clear the current html 
        $("#form").html('');

        // load a new background
        $('body').css({'background-image':data.background})

        // set up the new fields:
        $.each(data.fields, function( i, item ) {
            $("#form").append('<input type="text" value="' + item + '"/>');
        });
    });
}
```

This is just a sample, to give you an idea! It's untested also ;)

Comment: i want to parse the value from HTML to PHP but i can't do this without AJAX, because PHP is serverside.

Comment: This will mean i can only catch the POST in a new page? i want to be able to handle it in the same page without redirecting or anything.

Comment: That would mean that you have to divide your PHP page in a section that purely handles $_POST data and one that does all the rest.  That's what an AJAX request is all about: sending a GET or POST request to a serverside page that can parse the data.

Comment: I have done that, I have made an AJAX script that POSTs a variable to formhandler.php, but what can I do with the .php script now? because game.php is already fully called, so he doesn't know the variable is set, should I use Javascript for checking which button is clicked?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, functionally? Normally with AJAX, you would update the HTML DOM based on the response that you get back from the AJAX request. You could, for instance, hide some buttons or show/create other buttons, all using just javascript...

Comment: I am trying to archieve when you click on 1 of the 4 buttons, something will check if you pressed the right button ( for example the image is an apple, therefore you need to press the button that says this is an apple, if you press this button you will get score depending on how much time you had left, otherwise you will get a penalty or lose some time, something like that ) so it knows which button is right and which one is wrong, and when time is 0 or you pressed the right button the background changes, and you play it again untill no more levels are left, all of this happens within 1 page.

Comment: Why does it all have to be just 1 page? Why can't the AJAX request be handled by a separate PHP page? Anyway, have your PHP return the new button set and the background img source to be shown in JSON format, so your javascript can render a different background and setup a new choice for the user after each time the user has made his/her choice.

Comment: It can be done in another page and then returned to the mainpage, thats what i tried to do, but because the main page is loaded it wont recheck all the variables.